# How to run code for multiple dataframe items

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
      df_Station = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Station 1024', 'Station 1024',
                              'Station 1024', 'Station 1024',
                              'Station 5588', 'Station 5588',
                              'Station 1211', 'Station 1211',
                              'Station 1211', 'Station 1200'], 
                       'Type': ['Weather_type1', 'Weather_type2',
                                'Weather_type2', 'Weather_type3',
                                'Weather_type1', 'Weather_type1',
                                'Space_type4', 'Space_type5',
                               'Space_type4', 'Space_type5']})


      print(df_Station)

               Name            Type
          Station 1024    Weather_type1
          Station 1024    Weather_type2
          Station 1024    Weather_type2
          Station 1024    Weather_type3
          Station 5588    Weather_type1
          Station 5588    Weather_type1
          Station 1211    Space_type4
          Station 1211    Space_type5
          Station 1211    Space_type4
          Station 1200    Space_type5
```

I apply one filter, according to a constant that is defined:

```
       cteName = 'Station 1024'
       df_Station_Specific_Name = df_Station[df_Station['Name'] == cteName]
```

I apply another filter, according to a constant that is defined:

```
       cteType = 'Weather_type2'
       df_Station_Specific_Name_Type = df_Station_Specific_Name[df_Station_Specific_Name['Type'] == 
                                       cteType]
```

Then, I do several operations on the filtered dataframe. For example, inserting a new column:

```
       df_Station_Specific_Name_Type['New_Columns'] = 1

       print(df_Station_Specific_Name_Type)

            Name              Type       New_Columns
         Station 1024   Weather_type2         1
         Station 1024   Weather_type2         1
```

Finally, I save this final dataframe. The file of type csc will contain the name of the two constants for easy identification.

```
          df_Station_Specific_Name_Type.to_csv('Result_%s_%s' %(cteName, cteType))
```

The code works perfectly. My question is as follows:

I would like to generate several outgoing dataframes, as changing the two constants, that is, making a combination between them.

For example, for cteName = Station 1024 I would like to run for all unique types (Weather_type1, Weather_type2 ...)

Would there be an automatic way to do this? without having to keep changing the constants cteName and cteType.

Note: the operation performed, adding a column, is just an example. After filtering the dataframe, several operations are performed. I am using Jupyter Anaconda line execution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Make a list of your "constants" and iterate through the list

Comment: use lambda   

cteName = 'Station 1024' 
cteType = 'Weather_type2'
result = df_Station[df_Station.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] == cteName and  x['Type']== cteType,axis=1)]
print(result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and loop over each groups:

```
for (cteName, cteType), df_ in df_Station.groupby(['Name', 'Type']):
    #to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning
    df_ = df_.copy()
    # do your stuff
    df_['New_Columns'] = 1
    # save to CSV
    df_.to_csv('Result_%s_%s' %(cteName, cteType))
```

if you have a list of couples (cteName, cteType) you want, you could add a `if` like:

```
l_couples = [('Station 1024', 'Weather_type2')]
for (cteName, cteType), df_ in df_Station.groupby(['Name', 'Type']):
    if (cteName, cteType) in l_couples:
        #to avoid SettingWithCopyWarning
        df_ = df_.copy()
        # do your stuff
        df_['New_Columns'] = 1
        # save to CSV
        df_.to_csv('Result_%s_%s' %(cteName, cteType))
```

Comment: I have one more question: during my specific executions "of your stuff" I use another different dataframe, but it is also filtered by the (cteName, cteType) fields. How do I include these lines within the for?

Comment: @JaneBorges maybe use `otherdf_ = otherdf[otherdf['Name'].eq(cteName)&otherdf['Type'].eq(cteType)]` to select the rows from the other dataframe with same Name and Type?

Comment: I would like to know what it would look like in case you have two different data frames. However, both would like to select by the same filters from (cteName, cteType)

Comment: @JaneBorges not sure to understand your question, in the previous comment I wrote how to select the same cteName and cteType in another dataframe. so if you put this in the loop, then you have the rows from the other dataframe that will have the same name and type than the current iteration

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a new dataframe with your unique name values, and then iterating through the new dataframe:

```
df_Station = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Station 1024', 'Station 1024',
                                    'Station 1024', 'Station 1024',
                                    'Station 5588', 'Station 5588',
                                    'Station 1211', 'Station 1211',
                                    'Station 1211', 'Station 1200'],
                           'Type': ['Weather_type1', 'Weather_type2',
                                    'Weather_type2', 'Weather_type3',
                                    'Weather_type1', 'Weather_type1',
                                    'Space_type4', 'Space_type5',
                                    'Space_type4', 'Space_type5']})

for _name, _type in zip(df_Station['Name'], df_Station['Type']):
    df_Station_Specific_Name = df_Station[df_Station['Name'] == _name]
    df_Station_Specific_Name_Type = df_Station_Specific_Name[df_Station_Specific_Name['Type'] == _type]
    df_Station_Specific_Name_Type['New_Columns'] = 1
    df_Station_Specific_Name_Type.to_csv('Result_%s_%s' % (_name, _type))
```

Comment: I believe that the form you used for cte_Types is incorrect. The way you have implemented the list will be:['Weather_type1', 'Weather_type1', 'Space_type4', 'Space_type5']. 
Would it be more appropriate to use a list of all types? such as: cte_Types = df_Station['Type].unique() ?  thank you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to just go through each combination in your dataframe without looking for uniques, as I've re-read your question and that's what it seems you're asking for

Comment: Understand. Does it mean that if I use your implementation I will already make only the combinations that I have in the data frame? But if I use unique () will I be executing all the combinations? Do I feel that some can generate an empty output dataframe (since they do not exist)?

Comment: This implementation essentially combines (name, type) into one object - so you'll always have 1st name, 1st type -> 2nd name, 2nd type -> 3rd name, 3rd type etc etc

Comment: When I run the code the following error appears: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '' ...]. Do you know how to solve it? The code is inside a folder on the desktop

Comment: Add the path where you want to save the file to the first parameter of to_csv: to_csv('your\\path\\here\\Result_%s_%s.csv' % (_name, _type)). Notice that you'll need to add the file extension as well

Comment: I made: df_Station_Specific_Name_Type.to_csv('C:\\Users\\jane\\Desktop\\namepast\\Result_%s_%s' %(_name, _type))

But the error continues. You know why?

Comment: Add print(os.getcwd()) to the start of your code, then save your file to a location on that path.

Comment: When I run: os.getcwd()     Returns: 'C:\\Users\\jane\\Desktop'.    
So, I copy that segment and do: df_Station_Specific_Name_Type.to_csv('C:\\Users\\jane\\Desktop\\Result_%s_%s' % (_name, _type)), but 
but the same error keeps showing up. Don't know how we can solve. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215846/discussion-between-bm13563-and-jane-borges).